# How can I add an user specific string to act as a key for a simple cypher?

Tags: c, string, caesar-cipher

I am modifying this simple qwerty cypher so it accepts a key of the users choosing, can I just add the string to replace the hard coded key or is there more to do?

I have tried using a string from a scanf user input.
It does work when the is hard coded in place but I would like to be able to add it as a user.

The original code I am working off is:

```
char* ciphertext = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";    

    char input[500];                                    
    printf("Enter text: ");
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);                 
    input[strlen(input) - 1] = 0;                       
    int count = strlen(input);                           
    char output[count];                                 
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {                    
        int index = ((int) input[i]) - 97;             
        if(index < 0) {
            output[i] = ' ';                            
        }
        else {
            output[i] = ciphertext[index];
```

I replaced:

```
char* ciphertext = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
```

with:

```
char KEY[26];                                        
    printf("Enter key text:");
    fgets(KEY, sizeof(KEY), stdin);
```

As well as swapping ciphertext[index] for KEY[index] in the final line.

My code looks like:

```
char KEY[26];                                        
    printf("Enter key text:");
    fgets(KEY, sizeof(KEY), stdin);                     

    char input[999];                                    
    printf("Enter text: ");
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);                 
    input[strlen(input) - 1] = 0;                       
    int count = strlen(input);                          

    char output[count];                                 
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {                     
        int index = ((int) input[i]) - 97;              
        if(index < 0) {
            output[i] = ' ';                            
        }
        else {
            output[i] = KEY[index];                     
        }
    }
    output[count] = 0;                                  

    printf("output: %s\n", output);
```

The code runs, allows and input for KEY but then skips allowing the user to add a text to encrypt and prints a letter as the encrypted message.

When I use the key: qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm
it prints d (13th input)
when I use: qazwsxedcrfvtgbyhnujmikolp
it prints y (16th input)
When I use: qazxswedcvfrtgbnhyujmkiolp
It prints n (again the 16th input)

Comment: Tangential to your main issue — Using `97` in `int index = ((int) input[i]) - 97;` is not as clear as saying what you mean: `int index = ((int) input[i]) - 'a';`.  Now it is only vulnerable to some misuses - translating upper-case letters, digits and most punctuation to spaces isn't the obvious behaviour.  Also, using different letters as the key converts from a Caesar cipher to an alternative (Vigenere, I believe).

Comment: Note that `fgets()` includes a newline (if there's room) and a null byte.  You only allow 26 characters, which means at most 25 letters plus a null byte will be used.  A minimum fix is to allocate 27 characters; 28 would be safer.

Comment: Because you are omitting the newline from the key string (because it isn't long enough), the next `fgets()` reads the leftover newline — and thinks it is done.  You should probably verify the length of the key that's read, too.